# Neat ruby way of returning failure or continuing after function call

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I often have code of the following nature

```
ret = function_call( arguments )
return -1  if ret == -1

ret = another_function_call( arguments2 )
return -1 if ret == -1

... pattern repeated several times
```

and so on one after another. I was wondering if there was another way in ruby of wrapping the return -1 if ret == 1 around the function call such that the code returns -1 if the function returns -1 or continues otherwise

Comment: No need to use error return codes when you have exceptions.

Comment: Do you want to do `return -1 if ret == -1` or `return -1 if ret == 1`? Which?

Comment: Aren't exceptions heavy? I mean exceptions are there but they should be for exceptional scenarios. E.g user enters wrong arguments isn't exceptional, it is to be expected. So I would not want to use exceptions to verify some values are fine. Not so sure on "No need to use error return codes part of it"

Comment: @sawa, I want return -1 if ret == -1. It should continue on to next statement if ret != -1

Comment: "Heavy" isn't a concept well-suited to Ruby: _All_ of Ruby is heavy.  Aim first for the clearest, simplest possible code.  Only if it proves to be too slow should it be changed

Comment: @WayneConrad, I agree when you put it that way. Was trying to see if there was something already out there for code that is already in this shape.

Comment: @av501 Then you should edit your question to remove the contradiction.

Comment: @sawa,not sure what you mean. I have put return -1 if ret == -1 and this automatically flows to next statement if ret != -1

Comment: @av501 That is what you put in the code. I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @av501: is `function_call` yours or external? a Ruby function that returns `-1` to signal an error is very unidiomatic, but maybe it's a special scenario.

Comment: I don't think this code is a common pattern in ruby but I have seen it often in java code. So I assume this can be written better in ruby. But How? So +1 for the Question from me!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of DRY maybe? Something like

```
def call_func(_method, arguments)
  raise "your exception" if send(_method, arguments) == -1
end

call_func(:function_call, arguments)
call_func(:another_function_call, arguments2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return_minus_one_on_one = Proc.new do |method_name, arguments|
  return -1 if send(method_name, arguments) == 1
end

return_minus_one_on_one.call("function_call", arguments)
return_minus_one_on_one.call("function_call2", arguments)
```